# Is it possible to query both from entity and list object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to query from both the entity and a list object.  Say I have an entity called "Customer", and I have a list of potential customers of object Potential.

```
Customer {
    id, name, address, ...
}

Potential {
    id, name, address, ...
}
```

In my repository I write the query as follows if I want to customize the query to get customers

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.status = :status")
List<Customer> findAllSpecialCustomers(String status)
```

But if I currently have a list object

```
List<Potential> potentials
```

And I want to include it in the Query above, how should I do it?  Or is it even possible?  The reason why I want to do this is because both entities represent different tables but i want to do sorting and pagination on the combined records of the two entities.  Also, `potentials` is queried from graph database.  While entity Customer is from mysql database.

Basically, I have a `potentials` list object that is queried from graph database.  I want to union it with `Customer` entity from a mysql database through @Query and apply sorting and pagination to the combined records.

Comment: Your questions is not clear at all. Are you saying, that you use two different databases? What do the classes `Potential` and `Customer` look like? You make it look like they have identical content and do not have a relation with each other.

Comment: I just make the fields identical for simplicity.  `Potential` is from a graph database.  `Customer` is from mysql database.  So it's difficult for me to union them since they are from different databases.  For mysql I have no issue since I can construct the SQL in the @Query... but I don't know if it's even possible to include the potentials list in this query so i can combine it with the Customer query.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? The JPA query just generates SQL queries and sorting, filtering etc. happens in the (MySQL) Database. This is fast an efficient and you get a small (hopefully) result set handed back. Your DB doesn't know of the result list from the graph DB. You would have to fetch _all_ customers and manually merge, sort and filter the lists. But that is a **bad** idea, bc this will be extremely slow, use a lot of memory and doesn't scale at all.

Comment: The question is, are the `Potential`s _also_ in the MySQL DB, i.e., do _all_ of them have a corresponding `Customer`? If not, can you create entries for them?
Otherwise, using plain SQL, a table value constructor for the Potential result list unioned with the Customer table might be possible. But that might get extremely complicated and will probably be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use a native union query and instead of using `Customer` or `Potential`, create another POJO class to map query results.

Comment: Customer is from mysql database; while Potential is from graph database.

Comment: This changes everything, you can even create an entity superclass using SpringData, but you won't be able to query two different data sources at the same time to perform paging and sorting, unless you could add an aggregation and indexing layer like Elasticesearch.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is some property in your Potential class that identifies a Customer. For argument's sake, let's assume that the id field in the two classes are the same, e.g., you want to pair up the Potential with id == 123 with the Customer with id == 123.

The simplest thing that I can think of is to map the list of Potentials to a list of Integers (or whatever type the id is), and then use that as a parameter to an "in" clause in your Customer query. For example,

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id in :idList")
List<Customer> findCustomersById(List<int> idList)
```

and

```
findCustomersById(
 potentials
  .stream()
  .map(Potential::getId)
  .collect(Collectors.toList()
);
```

As far as "zipping" the two lists, i.e. pairing up the matches from the two lists, I'll leave that as an exercise for you :-)

Comment: these 2 entities are totally unrelated.  but i am combining them since i need to present the list of customers and potential customers in one collection.  So, this is not the solution.  Also, i need to apply sort and pagination on the combined list.

Comment: also, customer list is from mysql database... while potential list is queried from graph database